# Distance is Quantitative continuous, Quantitative continuous on a ratio scale or Quantitative continuous in scale of intervals?

Tags: continuous-data, variable

I have sample data and I have one variable which records distance from resident to place of work. I have to chose that this variable is actually of what type.
It is Quantitative continuous for sure. But I am confused that it justifies which category more? Quantitative continuous on a ratio scale or Quantitative continuous in scale of intervals. Kindly share your opinion.

Also, I recorded Body Temperature (Fahrenheit) of subjects as Quantitative continuous on a interval scale. Because Body Temperature can either be meausured in Fahrenheit or Celsius. They both belong to interval scale. While Kelvin belongs to Ratio scale as it has absolute zero. Right?

Comment: This looks like an assignment to me. Here's a hint. A ratio scale has a zero point that isn't arbitrary. How are you measuring body temperature? Fahrenheit and Celsius both have arbitrary zeros.

Comment: Yes, Actually it is assignment.  I have started with statistics and this was part of that.  I understood the overall concept of Quantitative and Qualitative but I am confused in further classification.

Comment: You could measure human body temperature in K. It just wouldn't be conventional.